# ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type - recaptcha - not able to login admin panel

Tags: google-recaptcha

I tried to login through admin panel for one of my Magento site but it is showing error as

ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type - recaptcha and not able to login.

[image]

Actually I changed the google recaptcha keys values of existing project from v2 to v3 for contact page after that only I am not able to login.

Also customer view of the site is also blank

Please help to overcome this issue as I am new to magento.

Answer (score 0):

**Try disable this captcha from terminal, this is the command**

To Disable **admin** login captcha

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/captcha/enable 0
```

To Disable **frontend** captcha

```
php bin/magento config:set customer/captcha/enable 0
```

Comment: I tried above i am getting error as below.                                                                             The XML in file "/app/code/Plazathemes/Themeoptions/etc/adminhtml/system.xml" is invalid:
Element 'resource': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not accepted by the pattern '([A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){1,}_[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]{1,}::[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,}'.
Line: 16

Element 'resource': 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'typeAclResourceId'.
Line: 16

Verify the XML and try again.

Comment: After changing the plazathemes_themeoptions::config as Plazatheme_Themeoptions::config above error got fixed. And i run config:set admin/captcha enable 0 and cache:flush then also i get ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type

Comment: Bug got fixed when I changed MSP_ReCaptcha' => 1 value as 0 in config file. Anyway thanks for your immediate responses

Comment: May you please upvote my answer.